# Select irregular cell ranges to sum values from another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, range

Working with excel, I have values in a column in irregular intervals (from every row to every 5 rows).  In a second column, could be or not values.  I need to sum in a third column the values of the second column based in the range of cells of the first column. Since it could be a very large list, I just need to copy the formula in col3 all the way down. (maybe the image is better than following text)

[[image: range selection 2][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jpm92.png)

|  | col1 | col2 | col |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | none | value1 |  |
| 2 | none | none |  |
| 3 | data 1 | value2 | sum 1 to 3 |
| 4 | data 2 | none | sum 4 to 4 |
| 5 | none | value3 |  |
| 6 | data 3 | value4 | sum 5 to 6 |
| 7 | none | value5 |  |
| 8 | none | none |  |
| 9 | data 4 | value6 | sum 7 to 9 |
| 10 | none | none |  |
| 11 | data 5 | none | sum 10 to 11 |
| 12 | none | value7 |  |
| 13 | none | none |  |
| 14 | none | value8 |  |
| 15 | none | none |  |
| 16 | data 6 | none | sum 12 to 16 |
| 17 | data 8 | value 9 | sum 17 to 17 |

I tried to use LOOKUP to find the previous value in col1 and get the position of that cell, but I can not select the range of the column 2

Comment: In image it seems your are using merged cells. Are they merged cell in your real case?

Answer (score 1):

Merged cells represents values in first cell of merged range. So, it would be easier to show sum of values to adjacent cell of merged range. Try-

```
=DROP(REDUCE("",A2:A7,LAMBDA(ra,rx,VSTACK(ra,IF(rx="","",SUM(FILTER(B2:B7,SCAN(0,A2:A7,LAMBDA(a,x,IF(x="",a,x)))=rx)))))),1)
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry Harun24r, they are not merged cells, I only gray out them to try to separate ranges

Answer (score 0):

Here is another alternative approach:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a, SCAN(0,B2:B18,LAMBDA(x,y,IF(y="",x,y))),
     b, IF(C2:C18="",0,C2:C18),
     c, MMULT(N(TOROW(a)=a),b),
     DROP(SORT(HSTACK(a,SEQUENCE(ROWS(a)),IF(B2:B18="","",c)),{1,2},{1,-1}),,2))
```

---

Note: This only assumes from your screenshot posted in OP that the range B2:B18 have merged cells and merged cells usually occupy the first cell of the merged cell ranges.

---

If the cells are not merged in column B i.e. `Column 1` in your screenshot and the value seats on the last cell of each groups then, try the following formula:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a, SORT(SCAN(,SORTBY(B2:B18,SEQUENCE(ROWS(B2:B18)),-1),LAMBDA(x,y,IF(y=0,x,y)))),
     b, IF(C2:C18="",0,C2:C18),
     c, MMULT(N(TOROW(a)=a),b),
     IF(B2:B18="","",c))
```

---

One more alternative way:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a, B2:B18,
     b, SORT(SCAN(,SORTBY(a,-SEQUENCE(ROWS(a))),LAMBDA(x,y,IF(y,y,x)))),
     IF(a,MAP(b,LAMBDA(s,SUM(FILTER(C2:C18,b=s)))),""))
```

---

Comment: Mayukh Bhattacharya, thanks for you help... but they are not merged cells. Just gray out cell to separate ranges.  I changed picture, maybe it es easier to see it.

Comment: @GabrielJarrin yes i have posted both ways, please follow the answer. The second approach shows that

Comment: @GabrielJarrin or you can use the third approach as well. Second or third anyone

Answer (score 0):

=MAP(B2:B18,C2:C18,LAMBDA(x,y,IF(ISBLANK(x),"",SUM(INDEX($C$2:y,IF(ISBLANK(x),"",IFERROR(LARGE(IF($B$2:x<>"",ROW($B$2:x)-1),2)+1,1))):INDEX($C$2:y,IF(x<>"",ROW(x)-1,""))))))

Another alternative could be LAMBDA with MAP.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).